# Ajax (Form Submission) Calls back Error function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a "contact us" form and everything is working but my error callback in the ajax runs instead of the success. I ajax is called, the PHP file runs, and I get an email to my localhost (using Mercury).

So why is my success callback not running? I have no idea how to find out what is causing the error especially since everything works.

The only thing I suspect is the file folders. The current structure is this. My html file and php file are in the root directory. The JS file is in a folder.

Here is a screenshot of the network tab in chrome debugger after I press submit
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2q7r.png

**My Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#main-contact-form").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sendingemail').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url : "../sendemail.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : new FormData(this),
            contentType : false,
            cache : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#sendingemail').fadeOut();
                $('#emailsent').fadeIn();
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

**My PHP:**

```
<?php
// ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
// error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-type: application/json');

// WE SHOULD ASSUME THAT THE EMAIL WAS NOT SENT AT FIRST UNTIL WE KNOW MORE.
// WE ALSO ADD AN ATTACHMENT KEY TO OUR STATUS ARRAY TO INDICATE THE STATUS OF OUR ATTACHMENT:
/*$status = array(
 'type'=>'Error',
 'message'=>'Couldn\'t send the Email at this Time. Something went wrong',
 'attachement'=>'Couldn\'t attach the uploaded File to the Email.'
 );*/

//Added to deal with Files
require_once ('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    //require_once('/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');
    //Get the uploaded file information
    $name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    //get the file extension of the file
    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] / 1024;
    //size in KBs

    //Settings
    $max_allowed_file_size = 10240;
    // size in KB
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "png");

    //Validations
    if ($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size) {
        $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size (~10MB). The file you attempted to upload is too large. To reduce the size, open the file in an image editor and change the Image Size and resave the file.";
    }

    //------ Validate the file extension -----
    $allowed_ext = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) {
        if (strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i], $type_of_uploaded_file) == 0) {
            $allowed_ext = true;
        }
    }

    if (!$allowed_ext) {
        $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. " . " Only the following file types are supported: " . implode(',', $allowed_extensions);
    }

    //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder - make sure the folder exists on the server and has 777 as its permission
    $upload_folder = "temp/";
    $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
    $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

    if (is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)) {
        if (!copy($tmp_path, $path_of_uploaded_file)) {
            $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
        }
    }
}
//--end

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$clientemail = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $clientemail . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$email = new PHPMailer();

$email -> From = $clientemail;
$email -> FromName = $name;
$email -> Subject = $subject;
$email -> Body = $body;
$email -> AddAddress('root@localhost.com');
//Send to this email

// EXPLICITLY TELL PHP-MAILER HOW TO SEND THE EMAIL... IN THIS CASE USING PHP BUILT IT MAIL FUNCTION
$email -> isMail();

// THE AddAttachment METHOD RETURNS A BOOLEAN FLAG: TRUE WHEN ATTACHMENT WAS SUCCESSFUL & FALSE OTHERWISE:
// KNOWING THIS, WE MAY JUST USE IT WITHIN A CONDITIONAL BLOCK SUCH THAT
// WHEN IT IS TRUE, WE UPDATE OUR STATUS ARRAY...
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    if ($email -> AddAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file, $name_of_uploaded_file)) {
        //$status[] = 'The Uploaded File was successfully attached to the Email.';
    }
}
// NOW, TRY TO SEND THE EMAIL ANYWAY:
try {
    $success = $email -> send();
    //$status['type'] = 'success';
    $status[] = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will reply as soon as possible.';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //$status['type'] ='Error';
    $status[] = 'Couldn\'t send the Email at this Time. Something went wrong';
}

// SIMPLY, RETURN THE JSON DATA...
die(json_encode($status));
```

Comment: are you sending anything back from php on success? I can't find anything. I guess Jquery is calling error-callback if nothing is returned.

Comment: The `error` callback function receives 3 arguments. I suggest you take advantage of them to help diagnose the problem: "*error: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )*" 'Cause really, what does `alert("Error");` do for error handling?

Comment: @Marcus I just used `alert("error")` to confirm it was running the error callback because everything works fine (I get the email with attachment and message)

Comment: @Jeff  no return just `die (json_encode($status));` ... do you have a suggestion of what I should return?

Comment: just return a 'success' or a 'true' or even a json obejct containing 'success'. Or the status you've created. just anything. `echo json_encode($status);` for example. But also make use of the error-callback as @Marcus said!

Comment: @Jeff I added the echo to the end of my code but it didn't change anything.